# I'm making a CLI hangman game, but one of my methods is "unreachable by pylance and the code isn't taking input. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylance

code thus far:

```
import random
# list of words
word_list = ["mangoes", "pomegranates", "strawberry", "oranges", "pineapples"]
word = random.choice(word_list)
print(word)

class Hangman():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def check_guess(self, guess):
        # checks if input is valid 
        if guess.isalpha() and len(guess) == 1:
            # Print if input is valid
            print("Input is valid")
        
        else:
            # Print if input is not valid
            print("Oops. Invalid input. Please enter a single alpabet")
        

        # Checks if input letter is in word and makes it lower case
        if guess in word:
            print(f"Good. {guess.lower()} is in the word.")
        else:
            print("Oops! Incorrect guess!")

    def ask_for_input(self):
        # gets user input and checks if the guess is valid
        while True:
            guess = input("Please enter a single letter: ")
             
        self.check_guess()

def game(self):
    play = Hangman()
    play.ask_for_input()
    play.check_guess()
    
game
```

initially I was missing the self parameter, but even after I added it, the check_guess method is still unreachable by pylance. So when i try to call it in the ask_for_input method, it does nothing. And the code doesn't take input either, it just prints a random word from the list.

Comment: `self.check_guess(guess)`. You didn't plug it in. You also never broke out of the while loop after the input was made.

Comment: Is this your real code? Really? What is the last line? `game`. Your code doesn't even run. What is the output of your program?

Comment: also your `while True` loop never ends. I assume you want the call to `check_guess()` to happen *inside* the loop, not *after* it.

Comment: @quamrana - there isn't going to be any output. It's stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy: So, not even: `"Please enter a single letter: "`?

Comment: @quamrana ~ I see, they didn't actually call `game`. I can't lie I don't read these kind of questions very hard. They are always due to typos and unfinished code, and they don't help anybody but the person with the question. If I spot an error or two, I throw out a comment about it and move on.

Comment: While your input is always useful, the OP hasn't confirmed whether this is their real code or not. As of now we are only guessing about what is wrong. My intuition says that they are actually calling `game()`, and are stuck in an infinite `input()` loop, but there are too many things wrong for me to trust it strongly in this case. Please vote to close.

Comment: @quamrana ~ you just gave every reason why this question isn't worth sitting on. You shouldn't have to yank the proper question out of the asker. There's thousands of other people asking questions that are the actual question, with code that is the actual code or at least a subset of it. Whatever the answer to this question is, it's a case the OP created and the answer is only going to help the OP. We could close this for "due to a typo" right now.